# Cannot return multiple value from function

Tags: c

I've been trying to run the following code. However, the only output i get is "Process returned 0(0x0). I cant seem to understand whats wrong with the code. I'm new to programming. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int argentina(int units,int a_price,int *as);

    int main()
    {
        int units,min_cost;
        int a_price=50;
        int a_stock=100;
        int b_stock=100;
        char country[10];
        printf("Enter the name of the country");
        gets(country);
        printf("Enter the number of units");
        scanf("%d",&units);
        if(country=="argentina")
        {
            min_cost=argentina(units,a_price,&a_stock);
            printf("%d : %d : %d",min_cost,b_stock,a_stock);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int argentina(int units,int a_price, int *as)
    {
        int cost;
        if(units >0 && units<=100)
        {
            cost=a_price * units;
            *as=*as - units;
            return cost;

        }


    }
```

Comment: 'if(country=="argentina") does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Why did you not notice the unexpected behaviour of the if statement when you stepped through the code with your debugger?

Comment: Hey how about using `strcmp` to compare strings buddy ? And  **try not to play with `gets`**

Comment: What you try to accomplish is presented in any C book or toturial. Please read it carefully!

Comment: And format your code properly! As given, it is messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set a `char[]` named toCompare (or something like that - you have to name it in such a way that you understand it in the future) and use `strcmp` to compare the strings. Read about the function here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm

```
char toCompare[15];
char country[15];
int ret;

strcpy(toCompare, "argentina");
gets(country);
ret = strcmp(toCompare, country);

if(ret == 0)
{
    min_cost=argentina(units,a_price,&a_stock);
    printf("%d : %d : %d",min_cost,b_stock,a_stock);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know to use strcmp. The problem is solved now!

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully you too will one day be answering other people's questions. EDIT - missed a couple of errors in my code snippet. Fixed now.

Comment: `gets()` is no longer a standard function in C  (C11).  Should your answer address that, maybe by using `fgets()` and coping with its trailing `'\n'`, it would be much better.